# Image Unavailable in facebook share debugger

Tags: facebook

I am debugging a url to check all 'og:image' property are set properly or not:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sinepulse.com%2Ftechnical-project-manager

Yes. It set. but when I debug this I can see the following error message:

```
Image Unavailable
Error while downloading http://sinepulse.com/sites/all/themes/smart_sinepulse/img/job/header.jpg with HTTP response code: 404
```

You can see that url pretty good: http://sinepulse.com/sites/all/themes/smart_sinepulse/img/job/header.jpg.

whats wrong from my end?

Comment: No, the image URL is not pretty good, I get only a 404 too, when I request that in my browser. _“whats wrong from my end?”_ - well that is something you must investigate, we don’t have access to the server ... start by checking the relevant log files.

Comment: Thank you. There is a permission issue. As I was logged in user I can see the url works. Now I change the og:image url with http://sinepulse.com/sites/default/files/qr_code/smart_home.png which is accessible for anonymous user. Till now I am getting the same issue. N.B: I re-scape

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ says that http://www.sinepulse.com/technical-project-manager currently only responds with a 500 error.

Comment: Now I can see all is good at facebook debugger: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sinepulse.com%2Fjob-open-list  but when I share image is broken.

Comment: That’s likely your local browser cache then ... works fine for me.